# Recommendations for Software to Create Equity Research Reports

Tags: microsoft-excel, reporting, finance, research, desktop-publishing

I'm researching software options suitable for creating equity research reports. I'm interested in solutions that offer the following capabilities:

Standardized templates for consistency across reports.
Integration with Excel for charts and financial models.
Output options in both PDF and web formats.
Efficient workflow for producing reports.
I seek recommendations based on experiences with software that meets these requirements, especially those tailored to financial or equity research. What software might fit these needs, and what features are crucial for this application?

Thanks for any insights!